# Why Spatie/Image package compresses the image even when only manipulating dimensions?

Tags: laravel

Take a look at this script:

```php
$path = 'storage/test-image.JPG';
$savePath = 'storage/test-image-saved.JPG';

$image = \Spatie\Image\Image::load(public_path($path));

$image
    ->height($image->getHeight()) // manipulating height to its original height
    ->save(public_path($savePath));

$originalSize = File::size(public_path($path));  // 1.7MB
$savedSize = File::size(public_path($savePath));  // 200KB
```

The result is that the image got compressed, and its colour changed. This is out of my expectation for an image manipulation tool.

Can anyone with experience care to explain it a bit?

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, you should do this question as [an issue in that repository](https://github.com/spatie/image/issues). They are better suit it to answer this one. I say this in a good way.

Comment: While opening a ticket on the repository seems to be getting the attention of the right persons, it may not be a valid "issue" after all. So I'm trying to get someone to probably, point out some fundamental mistake I may have made. If the question stale for a few days, then I'll probably turn to the repository authors...